# How to make use of RuntimeService in Ubuntu under UEFI boot mode?

Tags: bios, uefi, libraries

How to make use of RuntimeService in Ubuntu under UEFI boot mode?

I want to make use of the runtimeservice of UEFI BIOS, SetVariable() or GetVariable(), and so on. What I need to do, and any lib for it? Please help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

These are accessible from the kernel context, so you can't easily do this from userspace. You can read the UEFI variables via the /sys/firmware/efi/vars but the data is in binary format, so one needs to decode this.  The firmware test suite (fwts) has a tool to do this, use:

```
sudo apt-get install fwts
sudo fwts uefidump -
```